# How put pic with two headers in the same area in web page?

Tags: html, css, header

I created following web page along with a css file in which I am trying to put a pic with two lines in the header section, but the text lines come out from the header file. Thanks in advance.

```css
#header {
 background-color: lightblue;
 height: 150px;
}

#header h1, h2 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Perfect Page</title>
        <link href="css/tsgeneral.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id ="header">
            <img src="pics/ts1.jpg" height="150" width="150" alt="tsIncanda">
            <h1>Tss Fans Page</h1>
            <h2>Welcome Fans</h2>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could add float to the image: http://jsfiddle.net/g94hdq10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use float on the image.

```
#header img {
    float: left;
}
```